# Can countable nouns become uncountable by usage?

Tags: uncountable-nouns, countable-nouns

The words speaker and hearer are countable nouns according to the [Cambridge Dictionary.](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/hearer) And a countable noun should either used plural or be with an article.

But I see many use these words without any article in the singular form. For example see:

> It is very plausible that this transfer of thought contents from
>   speaker to hearer is a necessary condition for successful
>   communication. [Source](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=7nQI9Vj0WtcC&pg=PA144&lpg=PA144&dq=%22speaker%20to%20hearer%22&source=bl&ots=mydyHHOJ2l&sig=xlAlWTz5ANA-_G-bfysH2s3RO6c&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwibiu-uwvPWAhVlLsAKHVc2DdMQ6AEIKjAA)

So, my question is, can a countable noun become uncountable just by our usage?

Comment: It just became [anarthrous](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/anarthrous#English), not uncountable. Like the expression "Big deal!" doesn't make "deal" uncountable, just anarthrous.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Arguably one could say that the article has been elided. "...transfer of thoughts content from (a) speaker to (a) hearer..."

Comment: @WS2 I think so. Just like "Big deal!" is probably just a shortening of "That's a big deal". There are many cases where English permits you to omit words when there's no chance of confusion.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Why do nouns _become_ anarthrous ?

Comment: ' ... a countable noun should either used [in plural form] or be [used] with an article' is a woeful oversimplification. See the thread in the 'duplicate' call, and  [Can predicative complements not be bare noun phrases in English – ...](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/268282/can-predicative-complements-not-be-bare-noun-phrases-in-english-that-is-are-cl), for instance. There are many expressions, some more fixed than others (and countability hard to determine with some), where no articles are used. _From hand to mouth / from parent to child / from cow to cow_ ....

Comment: The speakers of English  determine whether any given noun is used as a count noun, a mass noun, or both, and speakers can change the usage, so yes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["He was neither seer nor prophet" – How would you explain the absence of an article?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/280998/he-was-neither-seer-nor-prophet-how-would-you-explain-the-absence-of-an-articl)