# Boy and girl meet (Why no article?)

Tags: articles, indefinite-articles

This article '[My Partner Is Ready To Get Married And I'm Not—What Do I Do?](https://www.womenshealthmag.com/relationships/relationships-not-wanting-to-marry)' starts with this:

> *If you’ve ever watched a romantic comedy, you know the drill. **Boy and girl** meet, fall in love, and all seems like it will be happily ever after. Then, there’s the twist: She wants to get married and he, the man-child he is, wants to live a bachelor life without a ring tying him down.*

Why is it there's no article in front of ***boy*** and/or ***girl***?

> ***A boy and girl** meet...*
>
> ***A boy and a girl** meet...*

Shouldn't it be either of the above?

Comment: Somewhat related: [Omission of the indefinite article to eliminate ambiguity](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/294671/omission-of-the-indefinite-article-to-eliminate-ambiguity) and [“He was neither seer nor prophet” How would you explain the absence of an article?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/280998/he-was-neither-seer-nor-prophet-how-would-you-explain-the-absence-of-an-articl) and [“With pen and paper” <— Why don't we need an article here?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/409338/with-pen-and-paper-why-dont-we-need-an-article-here/409339#409339)

Comment: It's headlinese: punchy non-standard deleted forms.

Answer (score 2):

"Boy meets girl" is a standard idiom referring to the classic romance plot. According to Google there have been both a film and a TV sitcom with that title in recent years. Your article has altered the phrase slightly to form the beginning of a sentence.

Comment: Do you mean that the "idiom" originated from the pop culture? OR vice versa?

Comment: The classic idiom/phrase is modified because, in today's world, girls can also meet boys and make, so to speak, the first move. The author is being "politically correct". It would be interesting to know if they are American and find out which year the article was written.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Does any of you have any proof that the article omission is because this phrase is an idiom?

Comment: @JK2 The article is missing because movie plots are like cooking recipes, the "boy meets girl" "boy falls in love" and "boy loses girl" are the *ingredients* necessary for making a romantic movie.

Comment: Is this http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/BoyMeetsGirl sufficient proof?

Comment: Not to mention this great song by Haircut 100: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G2cat4kykzI (_Boy meets girl_)